# When I select correct answer it returns false in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Why return false when I select correct answer? I have question and answers. Question and answers are random elements. There are one question and four answers. When I select corrrect answer it returns false. Why is this happening? I am tried solving this problem. I cannot figure out why this happening. How to solve this?

```
var characters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',];
final random = Random();
var randomElement = characters[random.nextInt(characters.length)];
var randomElement2 = characters[random.nextInt(characters.length)];
var randomElement3 = characters[random.nextInt(characters.length)];
var randomElement4 = characters[random.nextInt(characters.length)];
var answers = [randomElement, randomElement2, randomElement3, randomElement4];

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int selectedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'Select: $randomElement',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: answers.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor:
                          selectedIndex == index ? Colors.grey : Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedIndex = index;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      answers[index],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  randomElement = characters[random.nextInt(characters.length)];
                });
                randomElement2 = characters[random.nextInt(characters.length)];
                randomElement3 = characters[random.nextInt(characters.length)];
                randomElement4 = characters[random.nextInt(characters.length)];
                setState(() {
                  answers = [
                    randomElement,
                    randomElement2,
                    randomElement3,
                    randomElement4
                  ];
                });
                answers.shuffle();
                if (randomElement == answers[selectedIndex]) {
                  debugPrint('correct');
                } else {
                  debugPrint('false');
                }
                selectedIndex = -1;
              },
              child: Text('Next'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you first generate a new answers batch in which the variable `randomElement` also gets a new random value. And then you are checking if that new random value is the same as the old one that the user has selected.

To solve this, you should move the logic to check if the user has selected correctly. You should generate a new random set only when a new question has been loaded and also the checking part for the old question has been done.